# Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint on table 'ImageTag' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many, entity-framework-core, cascading-deletes

In Entity Framework Core, I'm attempting to create a system with 4 Db Models - Image, Tag, ImageTag, User.  Image and Tag are a many to many relationship, which is provided by the ImageTag table.  Images and Tags are also directly linked to Users in a many to one relationship (Images are the property of Users, so it's a required relationship), so when a User is deleted it should cascade and delete all Images, Tags & ImageTags belonging to that User.  When I try to implement this and do an Update-Database with the code below I get an error of:

*Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_ImageTag_Tags_TagId' on table 'ImageTag' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.*

After much trial and error, it seems one solution to the problem is to make UserId on Image and Tag nullable.  This changes the ReferentialAction in the constraints for the foreign key on those tables from ReferentialAction.Cascade to ReferentialAction.Restrict.  However...

1) I'm not entirely sure why this fixes the issue as the error refers to the ImageTag constraint, not the User one.

2) I don't want to make the relationship between the the Images/Tags and Users an optional/nullable one.

3) However this does get solved, ideally it would still allow cascading deletes where appropriate.

```
public class Image
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string FileExtension { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ImageTag> ImageTags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ImageTag> ImageTags { get; set; }
}

public class ImageTag
{
    public long ImageId { get; set; }
    public long TagId { get; set; }

    public virtual Image Image { get; set; }
    public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    ...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ImageTag>()
            .HasKey(x => new { x.ImageId, x.TagId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<ImageTag>()
            .HasOne(bc => bc.Image)
            .WithMany(b => b.ImageTags)
            .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.ImageId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ImageTag>()
            .HasOne(bc => bc.Tag)
            .WithMany(c => c.ImageTags)
            .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.TagId);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have understood the problem and you have also understood what you have  to do to overcome this but what solution or suggestion are expecting from us?

Comment: Thank you for your response TanvirArjel.  It is because the solution I came up with, although solving the immediate problem, creates another problem whereby Image & Tag no longer have a required relationship with User.  In terms of data integrity that is not a good idea, and in terms of readability/understanding the intent of the code/db it is also not great.  See points, 1,2 and 3.

Comment: Then `ReferentialAction.Restrict` would be the best solution for you.

Comment: Yeah, I discovered ReferentialAction.Restrict on the ImageTag model building solves the problem today.  Only issue is I think that will prevent cascade deletes for ImageTag (when i delete an image it would be nice if it went and deleted all ImageTags related to it). Do you think there's any solution which will still allow cascade deletes from Images => ImageTags?

Comment: Did you get that resolved?